# Understanding the behaviour of subsetting using 'which'

Tags: r, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I was trying to define a function generating all the prime numbers till n.
I came up with the following solution, which I compared to a [solution readily available](https://saysmymind.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-r-and-sql/) (given below for reference). Essentially there's just a line of difference in both the codes (indicated below)

```
sieve <- function(n){
sq.n <- sqrt(n)
vec <- 2:n
primes <- rep(0, times=(sq.n))
i <- 1
while (!(is.na(primes[i] < sq.n)) && (primes[i]) < (sq.n)) {
    primes[i] <- vec[1]
    vec <- vec[which(vec%%primes[i] != 0)] # This keeps all the numbers not divisible by 
    # the prime in question
    i <- i + 1
}
return(c(primes[which(primes!=0)], vec))
}
```

Curious about efficiency, a google search yielded the following code -

```
getPrimeNumTilln <- function(n) {
a <- c(2:n)
l <- 2
r <- c()
while (l*l < n) {
    r <- c(r,a[1])
    a <- a[-(which(a %% l ==0))] # This removes all the numbers which are 
    # divisible by the prime in question
    l <- a[1]
}
c(r,a)
}
```

Both solutions work okay. (The internet solution gives a wrong answer if n is the square of a prime, but that can be corrected easily)

And these are the microbenchmark results -

```
microbenchmark(sieve(100),getPrimeNumTilln(100),times=100)
Unit: microseconds
                  expr     min      lq      mean  median      uq     max neval
            sieve(100) 142.107 153.106 165.85155 162.785 165.425 466.795   100
 getPrimeNumTilln(100)  41.797  47.076  51.09312  49.276  51.036 126.269   100
```

I would like to understand the fair difference in the runtime of both the functions

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legit question in my mind...

Comment: I think it's valid, but it might remind people of code review questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop of the first function does 10 iterations for `n = 100`, the second function does 4.

```
sieve <- function(n){
  sq.n <- sqrt(n)
  vec <- 2:n
  primes <- rep(0, times=(sq.n))
  i <- 1
  while (!(is.na(primes[i] < sq.n)) && (primes[i]) < (sq.n)) {
    count <<- count + 1
    primes[i] <- vec[1]
    vec <- vec[which(vec%%primes[i] != 0)] # This keeps all the numbers not divisible by 
    # the prime in question
    i <- i + 1
  }
  return(c(primes[which(primes!=0)], vec))
}

count <- 0
sieve(100)
#[1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
count
#[1] 10

getPrimeNumTilln <- function(n) {
  a <- c(2:n)
  l <- 2
  r <- c()
  while (l*l < n) {
    count <<- count + 1
    r <- c(r,a[1])
    a <- a[-(which(a %% l ==0))] # This removes all the numbers which are 
    # divisible by the prime in question
    l <- a[1]
  }
  c(r,a)
}

count <- 0
getPrimeNumTilln(100)
# [1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
count
#[1] 4
```

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful